# How to write a test to cover Survey Trigger?

Tags: survey, salesforce-survey

This is possible to create a trigger on Survey object, but DML operation insert is forbidden on Survey object. How one can cover Survey Trigger with a test?

Comment: I have seen a couple of questions around survey objects which are not writable. At this point it seems to be not allowed and unfortunately there wont be a way to cover and test the trigger. You may look at this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262793/how-would-i-test-a-trigger-on-non-writable-surveyresponse-object) or the [issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YmiaQAC&title=cannot-test-apex-trigger-on-surveyresponse). These links are for Survey response which has same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To test the trigger

```
trigger SurveyTrigger on Survey(before insert){
    //factor your logic to a  handler class and method
}
```

we could try to catch to exception of DML operation insert is now allowed

```
@isTest
private static void survey(){
    Survey s = new Survey();
    try{
        insert s;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.assertEquals(...); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Same applies to SurveyInvitation?

Comment: how does this code cover the trigger? I don't see how trigger would ever execute

Comment: statement execution `insert s;` should give coverage