# Salesforce Surveys - data migrations from old system

Tags: data-migration, survey, salesforce-survey

I have an old Survey app in my Salesforce org

Now I want to use Salesforce Surveys, but I do not want to loose the data of my old surveys - I still need that all the reports of surveys would include old and new data.

So I want to migrate all the old records into Salesforce Survey Responses

I know that the data model is different, and I can deal with that, but I found out that I cannot use DML in Apex to insert into the SurveyResponse object - from this article:

[How would I test a trigger on non-writable SurveyResponse object?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262793/how-would-i-test-a-trigger-on-non-writable-surveyresponse-object)

**QUESTION**

1. How can I migrate my old survey-response data into the new Salesforce SurrveyResponse object?
2. If I cannot migrate data, maybe there is a way to handle the old data and new data in same reports?

Comment: If you use Einstein Analytics / Tableau CRM you could build a dataset containing the Data from the two sources. Or you could build a custom object where you join the Data from the two sources and build some kind of batch processing / trigger to update the custom object records. The second idea is far away from perfect, but it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you @NinaRosen for the suggestion. But I want to use and stay with the standard Survey data and no other custom object, also I do not want a 3rd party to gather the data and show reports on it - it will be very expensive and mt project will be to big to implement. Any other idea?

Comment: No, but I'm pretty sure that the standard reporting will not be enough to solve your problem without an additional sObject or without pushing the new data into the old sObject structure. Instead of an sObject a big Object would work too(but then no standard Reporting). I think you need to take one of two ways, but they are both not really nice.